# How do I insert new divs inside an existing div?

Tags: dreamweaver

I worked on an existing project today and tried to insert a few new paragraphs and images to an existing page.

What happened, however, was that my new elements were created outside of the "main" container (which is centred), so the new elements were not aligned properly in the web browser. I discovered that the elements need to be inside the main content div, but I don't know how to insert them in there. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your html code. However you have to put your custom `div` inside the `<div id="main">... </div>` containert like this `<div id="main">... <div id="custom_div"><p>Your text paragraphs</p></div></div>`

Comment: Because the page is so big the HTML code is messy and unreadable (it's all absolutely positioned, but within the div). I would just edit the HTML if that was feasible, but it's not really.

Comment: I understand how to do it in HTML, but I really need a solution for doing it within the Dreamweaver GUI